# Enum case not found in type Int

Tags: ios, swift, enums, int

I'm going through a tutorial in *objective-c* and recreating the project in *swift* but have gotten stuck and can't figure out why the `enum` that is of type Int isn't unrecognizable to a switch statement that uses the type Int as well (or at least I think it is in my mind).

The error I'm getting is:

> Enum case 'PVMapBoundary' not found in type 'Int'

and here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit


enum PVMapOption: Int {
    case PVMapBoundary = 0,
    PVMapOverlay,
    PVMapPins,
    PVMapCharacterLocation,
    PVMapRoute

}

class PVMapOptionsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    var selectedOptions = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OptionCell")!

        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case .PVMapBoundary:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Park Boundary";
            break;
        case .PVMapOverlay:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Map Overlay";
            break;
        case .PVMapPins:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Attraction Pins";
            break;
        case .PVMapCharacterLocation:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Character Location";
            break;
        case .PVMapRoute:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Route";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


        if self.selectedOptions.contains(indexPath.row) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```